# Clarifications for storing images in sqlite database using nodejs and electron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sqlite, electron

So, i've been tinkering with nodejs to store images in my sqlite database i've managed to make it work but somehow i need some clarification or a suggestion on how to handle files with nodejs connecting to sqlite. I still haven't refractor the code but please bear with it.

What i did is after choosing the file, ipcRenderer will send the file to the backend(ipcMain) to create a temporary image which i can then access for previewing. I will also return to the frontend the data which i will save as a state as a string in a base64 format so that i could save it in the sqlite (i've tried querying using a file object but it does not work or im just not aware).

Choosing File

```
uploadFile(event) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);

        if (file) {
            ipcRenderer.send('uploadFile', [file.path, file.name, file]);
            console.log(file);

            ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', async (event, arg) => {
                let data = await arg;
                this.setState({
                    isImageReady: true,
                    image: data.toString('base64'),
                })
             })
          // axios.post('/files', data)...
        }
  }
```

Creating Temp Image

```
ipcMain.on('uploadFile', (event, arg) => {
    fs.writeFile('./src/assets/temp.png', '', (err) => {return null}); 
    fs.readFile(arg[0], (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        fs.writeFile('./src/assets/temp.png', data, (err) => {
                event.reply('asynchronous-reply', data);
                console.log("The file was succesfully saved!");
        }); 
    });

})
```

Previewing Image

```
 previewImage(event) {
        if(!this.state.isImageReady){
            let e = document.querySelector('.fileInput');
            e.style.boxShadow = "inset 0 0 0 1px red"
            setTimeout(() => {
                e.style.boxShadow = `inset 0 0 0 1px ${theme[ct].inputBorder}`
            }, 1000);
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            isImageFinal: true,
        })
        let doc = document.querySelector('.changeImagePreview');
        doc.src = require('../../assets/temp.png');
    }
```

Sending data for Construction of query

```
let queryData = {
                type: 'add',
                table: stmt.table.user.table,
                col: [
                    stmt.table.user.name,
                    stmt.table.user.password,
                    stmt.table.user.sleep,
                    stmt.table.user.companion,
                    stmt.table.user.image,
                ],
                value: [
                    this.state.name,
                    this.state.pass,
                    this.state.sleep,
                    this.state.companion,
                    this.state.image,
                ],
            }
let x = ipcRenderer.sendSync('runQuery', queryData);
```

Applying constructed query

```
await db.all(q, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          mes(3, err.message);
        }
        mes(1, "Query succesfully applied");
        // get the last insert id
        rows.forEach(element => {
        });

        event.returnValue = rows;
     });
```

Comment: Why would you store images in a database please? Surely it just means you can't see them without writing code to extract them and it makes your database unnecessarily large and less responsive?

Comment: Im trying to make a todo app with users in it i don't know any other way except saving user data(including images) in a database.